# react-router - Link with string form works but not object form

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router and `Link` just fine like below:

```
  <nav>
    ...
    {sidebarCollections.map((c, i) => (
      <Link to={`/collection?id=${c.id}`} key={c.id}>
        {c.name}
      </Link>
    ))}
  </nav>
```

But now I need to pass some data through the `Link`.

I found out in the [React Router Docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) that `Link` can alternatively take an object with a state field which is just what I need. Example from Docs:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/courses",
    search: "?sort=name",
    hash: "#the-hash",
    state: { fromDashboard: true }
  }}
/>
```

So I try:

```
 <nav>
    ...
    {sidebarCollections.map((c, i) => (
     <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/collection?id=${c.id}`,
          // state: { name: "test"}
        }}
        key={c.id}
      >
        {c.name}
      </Link>
    ))}
 </nav>
```

So I tried the above and suddently it's not rendering. I tried commenting out `state` and only using the `pathname` field to match the string form I had working before to no avail either.

What's going on and how can I pass some data through the link into my component? Is it because of the map function or the string interpolation that's perhaps messing it up somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters can't be added inside the `pathname` field when using the object syntax. It needs to be included as a `search` field. I ended up with this as a solution:

```
   <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/collection`,
          search: `?id=${c.id}`,
          state: { name: c.name },
        }}
        key={i}
      >
        {sc.name}
   </Link>
```

And then in my component I can access the state with:

```
location.state.name
```